# Unauthorized error in Back4App in fetch api on React Native android

Tags: react-native, back4app

I am trying to access [public database](https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/zip-codes-all-countries-in-the-world/get-started?appEntityId=85590331-13e6-4a3e-a528-7f216aca1cb7) of `back4app`. I'm using react-native and trying to access below API code:

```
const where = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
    "postalCode": postalCode
}));
const response = await fetch(
    `https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/IN?limit=10&where=${where}`,
    {
        headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': Constants.BACK4APP_API_KEY, // This is actual Application Id
            'X-Parse-Master-Key': Constants.BACK4APP_REST_API_KEY, // This is actual App Master Key

        }
    }
);
const data = await response.json();
```

I have tried to use **Javascript Key**,  **Client Key**,  **.NET Key**,  **REST API Key** but it is always giving `unauthorized` error to me. When i used **Master Key** for test(not recommended by Back4App), there was no error but it returned empty results, for the same query with Sample API KEY it returned data.

Can anybody help?

Comment: The right way to get data is by using App ID + Javascript Key in your frontend. Make sure that your initialization code is like this:

Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JS_KEY");
Parse.serverURL = "h ttps://p arseapi.back4app.com/" (I just put some spaces in the URL in order to show it properly

Comment: I'm not using Parse SDK. Its single API I want to 'fetch' in React native (not Javascript frontend).

Answer (score 0):

I received help from Back4App support team. Rether then master key header, `rest api key` worked well.

```
const where = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
    "postalCode": postalCode
}));
const response = await fetch(
    `https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/IN?limit=10&where=${where}`,
    {
        headers: {
            'dataType': 'json',
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': Constants.BACK4APP_API_KEY, 
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': Constants.BACK4APP_REST_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        }
    }
);
const data = await response.json();
```